# A Convergent Series and a Bounded/Monotone Sequence (Proof Verification)

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

I'm practicing my proof-writing and was hoping you could let me know if this proof looks good. I would like to know if the proof is incorrect, if there are parts that are overly wordy/complicated, or if I'm missing some element of a proof that is helpful to see, if not strictly necessary.

**The Prompt:**

Show that if $\sum{x_n}$ converges and $(y_n)$ is bounded and monotone (either increasing or decreasing), then $\sum{x_ny_n}$ converges.

**My Proof:**

Suppose $\sum{x_n}$ converges, so that for all $ε>0$ there exists a $n_ε$ such that $|\sum_n^m{x_n}| \le{ε}$ for all $m \le{n} \le{n_ε}$. If $sup |y_n|=0$ then $(y_n)$ is a sequence of all zeros and so $\sum{x_ny_n}=0$ and thus converges trivially. Now suppose $sup|y_n| \neq 0$ and define $ε_y = ε * sup|y_n|$. Since $(y_n)$ is bounded, $sup |y_n|$ is finite and so $ε_y$ is finite. Also, since $ε$ can be thought of as any element of $\{x|x>0\}$ and since $sup|y_n|$ is a positive constant, $ε_y ∈ \{x|x>0\}$ as $\{x|x>0\} = \{x|cx>0\}$ for any positive constant $c$. Then for every $ε_y>0$ there exists a $n_ε$ (the same $n_ε$ as for $\sum_n^m{x_n} \le{ε}$) such that:

$\sum_n^m{x_ny_n} \le{sup|y_n| * \sum_n^m{x_n}} \le{sup|y_n| * ε} = ε_y$

holds for all $m \le{n} \le{n_ε}$ and thus, $\sum{x_ny_n}$ is convergent.

***I didn't use the fact that $(y_n)$ was monotone in my proof. Am I missing something?**

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is wrong. Actually, if you exclude the assumption that $(y_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is monotonic, the statement is false, and so it cannot be proved. You were supposed to prove that $\bigl\lvert\sum_{k=m}^nx_ky_k\bigr\rvert<\varepsilon$, for each $\varepsilon>0$. You replaced $\varepsilon$ with another number and you forgot the absolute value.

By the way, what you are trying to proof is known as Abel's test.

Comment: I still don't fully understand where I went wrong. By using the term $ε_y$ I wanted to show that for any value greater than zero there exists a unique $n_ε$  such that $\sum_n^m{x_ny_n}$ is less than that value (I used $ε_y$ instead of $ε$ to signal that its mapping to the associated $n_ε$ values was different). If I renamed $ε_y$ as $ε$ wouldn't there still exist some number such that for $m\ge{n}\ge$ that number $\sum_m^n{x_ky_k}<ε$ for all $ε>0$? I also don't see how the fact that the equation should include the absolute value of the series changes the validity of the math?

Comment: Your goal is to prove that, for every $\varepsilon>0$, here is some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that if $n\geqslant n\geqslant N$, then $\lvert\sum_{k=m}^nx_ky_K\rvert<\varepsilon$, right?! And you did not prove that.